# jQuery change css based on class of another element

Tags: jquery, css, settimeout, event-listener

I have this code, it does check for a class and changes the CSS based on whether or not that class is present. However, it then keeps the CSS that way, with 37px top margin. How would I make it check again if the Class has been removed and change the CSS back?

```
function checkForStickyClass()
{
    if ($('.sticky-wrapper').hasClass('is-sticky'))
        $('#mobile-menu-wrap').css('top','37px');

    else
        setTimeout(checkForStickyClass, 100);
}

$(checkForStickyClass);
```

I tried to modify like

```
function checkForStickyClass()
{
    if ($('.sticky-wrapper').hasClass('is-sticky'))
        $('#mobile-menu-wrap').css('top','37px');

    else if
        (!$('.sticky-wrapper').hasClass('is-sticky'))
        $('#mobile-menu-wrap').css('top','0');
    else
        setTimeout(checkForStickyClass, 100);
}

$(checkForStickyClass);
```

Now this doesnt work because it keeps it at 0px at all times. Obviously I have some logic error here. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set that Timeout every time, so no `else` in front of `setTimeout`.

What is changing your class? Can you use that code to also change the style of `#mobile-menu-wrap`?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! here's the working code, thx to [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4421490/alex)

```
function checkForStickyClass()
{
    setTimeout(checkForStickyClass, 100);
    if (jQuery('.sticky-wrapper').hasClass('is-sticky'))
        jQuery('#mobile-menu-wrap').css('top','37px');

    else if (!jQuery('.sticky-wrapper').hasClass('is-sticky'))
        jQuery('#mobile-menu-wrap').css('top','0px');
}

jQuery(checkForStickyClass);
```